# Windows Authentication - Getting current user name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

In my MVC application I want to render a table in a cshtml file, if the current log in user is some x person. I am using windows authentication and I have made the following changes in web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
      </authentication>
```

And in my controller when I am trying to access the current user name I am not getting any user name. I am trying the following:

```
ViewBag.LogInUserName = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

This above line was working before. But I don't know whats wrong now. Also I have hosted my application on IIS now.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the web project's properties, in particular:

1. Anonymous Authentication - Set to "Disabled"
2. Windows Authentication - Set to "Enabled"

By default these are set to the opposite of what you're probably looking for.

[image: Web project properties]

(Image sourced from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx))

Answer (score 12):

You need to put the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller.

You can use `User.Identity.Name` in your controllers.

```
[Authorize]
public class YourController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you just show how I can achieve that.

Comment: I have just change my web project properties to use Asp.Net development server. And now I am able to retrieve the current log in user name. So problem is when I am hosting my web project on IIS. Any idea?

Comment: @Jash: The above code should work fine with windows authentication (even if anonymous access is turned on). Did you try it in IIS?

Comment: Yup it is working iwth windows authentication. Nut it is not working with IIS

Comment: User.Identity.Name returns string.Empty

Comment: Have you any solution for this.

Comment: I've never got the same problem as you and I use windows auth all the time doing like I described above.

Comment: Is your site hosted on IIS. does I need to add anything in web.config

Comment: HI i jsut added the Authorize attribute but after that it is throwin 4o1 unathorized error.

Comment: You have probably not installed the Windows Authentication feature in IIS.

Comment: if you remove [Authorize] then the 401.0 - Unauthorized goes away and you can get the user name like System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but this may serve others in the future.

I had the same problem once after deploying my site to a new IIS server, and the anonymous authentication was enabled, so make sure that anonymous authentication is disabled and it should work.