# How to retrieve current logged on user id from IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I need to retrieve the current logged on User ID in the IIS then I will pass that ID to a function for authentication purpose.

```
public ActionResult Login(myLoginModel model)
{
            System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user;
            user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
            String name = user.Identity.Name.ToString();

AuthenticateUser(name)
}
```

I always got a null value for "name". My web.config file is:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

and I have disabled Anonymous Authentication and enabled Windows Authentication on the IIS Manager. Can you help me fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Authentication - Getting current user name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968254/windows-authentication-getting-current-user-name) -- also, FWIW, by the time they hit "login" they're already authenticated from the AD (unless you're doing something else beyond basic authentication--which should probably happen in `Session_Start`)

Comment: I tried putting [authorize] on top of my controller method, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get user not from `HttpContext` but from `Controller` directly:

`Controller.User.Identity.Name` or just `User.Identity.Name`